# How can I call a generic delegate?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, delegates

This is code from an external library I have no control over:

```
public class Library {

    public delegate void Handler<T>(in T type);

    public void Subscribe<T>(Handler<T> handler) {
        // Whatever...
    }

}
```

This is my application code:

```
public class Application {

    public void Run() {
        var library = new Library();
        var types = new List<Type>() {typeof(int), typeof(string)};
        foreach(var type in types) {
            var methodLibrary = library.GetType().GetMethod("Subscribe");
            var methodLibraryGeneric = methodLibrary.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] {type});
            var methodApplication = this.GetType().GetMethod("OnHandler", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
            var methodApplicationGeneric = methodApplication.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] {type});

            // [EXCEPTION] System.ArgumentException: method arguments are incompatible
            var delegateApplication = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Library.Handler<>), methodApplicationGeneric);

            methodLibraryGeneric.Invoke(library, new object[] {delegateApplication});
        }
    }

    private void OnHandler<T>(in T type) {
        // Whatever...
    }

}
```

I hope it's clear what I'm trying to do: I have a whole bunch of types I determine at runtime (not just int/string for demo purposes), and I want all of them to be registered with the external library which calls back into my code.

As a workaround I could explicitly call `library.Subscribe<int>(OnHandler)` for each and every type, but that would be rather brittle and error-prone, and I thought generics could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create an instance of the *constructed* delegate type `Handler<Something>`, rather than the unbound `Handler<>`. Basically, you should call `MakeGenericType` on `typeof(Handler<>)`, just like you did on the two methods. You would also need to pass `this` to `CreateDelegate`, as `methodApplicationGeneric` is not a static method.

```
var delegateApplication = Delegate.CreateDelegate(
    typeof(Library.Handler<>).MakeGenericType(type),
    this,
    methodApplicationGeneric
);
```

Comment: Thanks. While your answer makes sense to me (the making it generic part), unfortunately it still throws the 'method arguments are incompatible' exception.

Comment: @Klemmbonzo I just noticed that `methodApplicationGeneric` is not `static`, so you need to pass `this` to `CreateDelegate` too. Check the edit.

Comment: It's working now! Thanks, you're a genius!